# Update set with value in table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-update

How can I do something like:

```
UPDATE table SET boolean = !boolean WHERE conditions
```

With an `ActiveRecord` model (Without using two queries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

users table in mysql

```
 active : tinyint(2)
```

in rails console

```
 User.update_all("active = !active", conditions)
```